# Bit planes of a 1-plane image in OpenCV only work for 1/3 of the image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to learn OpenCV by doing a few things on my own. In this particular case, I wanted to take the bit planes of a grayscale image. The code seems to have worked, but it only works well for the bit 7 and 6, not so much for the remaining 6, as it only shows a good result for about 1/3 of the image. I just haven't found what's wrong with it as of yet. I'd greatly appreciate some help on the matter, as I'm just doing my first codes with the libraries.

Here's what I get for the first bit:

[image]

And here is it for the 7th bit:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
   Mat m1 = imread("grayscalerose.jpg");
   imshow("Original",m1);
   int cols, rows, x, y;
   cols = m1.cols;
   rows = m1.rows;
   printf("%d %d \n",m1.rows,m1.cols);
   Mat out1(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
   out1 = (m1/128); //Here's where I divide by either 1,2,4,8,16,32,64, or 128 to get the corresponding bit planes

   for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
            out1.at<uchar>(y,x) = (out1.at<uchar>(y,x) % 2);
   } }

   out1 = out1*255;
   imshow("out1",out1);
   waitKey(0);
   destroyWindow( "out1" );

}
```

Thanks in advance. I hope my explanation wasn't too messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you divide `15` (`0x00001111`) by `2` (`0x00000010`) you get `7` (`0x00000111`), which is not what you expect. You can check if a bit is set like: `15 & 2`, which produces 0 if second bit is not set, else a value greater then 0. The same applies for other values.

Try the following code. Note that:

- you need to load the image as grayscale (using `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` in `imread`)
- you can directly put values either `0` or `255` when you select the bit

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat m1 = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    imshow("Original", m1);
    int cols, rows, x, y;
    cols = m1.cols;
    rows = m1.rows;
    printf("%d %d \n", m1.rows, m1.cols);
    Mat out1(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));


    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
            out1.at<uchar>(y, x) = (m1.at<uchar>(y, x) & uchar(64)) ? uchar(255) : uchar(0); //Here's where I AND by either 1,2,4,8,16,32,64, or 128 to get the corresponding bit planes
        }
    }

    imshow("out1", out1);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("out1");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First let's read the image in as grayscale only. (As mentioned by [user3896254](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3896254/user3896254)).

Then, let's prepare a mask image, where only the least significant bit is set -- i.e. all the values are 1.

Then the algorithm is simple. Let's avoid per-pixel manipulation (the two nested for loops), and try to take advantage of the optimized operations provided by OpenCV.

For each bit (0..7):

- Mask out the lowest order bit in the work image.
- Scale the masked image by 255 to make it black/white.
- Store the output.
- Divide values in work image by 2 -- i.e. shift all bits by 1 position to the right.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat input_img(cv::imread("peppers.png", 0));

    int32_t rows(input_img.rows), cols(input_img.cols);

    cv::Mat bit_mask(cv::Mat::ones(rows, cols, CV_8UC1));

    cv::Mat work_img(input_img.clone());
    std::string file_name("peppers_bit0.png");
    for (uint32_t i(0); i < 8; ++i) {
        cv::Mat out;
        cv::bitwise_and(work_img, bit_mask, out);

        out *= 255;
        cv::imwrite(file_name, out);

        work_img = work_img / 2;
        file_name[11] += 1;
    }
}
```

We can develop even shorter (and probably faster) version using a single [matrix expression](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions).

We can calculate the appropriate divisor using the expression `(1<<i)`. We divide every element by this value to shift the bits, mask each element by ANDing it with 1, and then scale all the elements by 255:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat input_img(cv::imread("peppers.png", 0));

    std::string file_name("peppers_bit0.png");
    for (uint32_t i(0); i < 8; ++i) {
        cv::Mat out(((input_img / (1<<i)) & 1) * 255);
        cv::imwrite(file_name, out);

        file_name[11] += 1;
    }
}
```

---

## Sample run

Input image:

[image]

Bit 0:

[image]

Bit 1:

[image]

Bit 2:

[image]

Bit 3:

[image]

Bit 4:

[image]

Bit 5:

[image]

Bit 6:

[image]

Bit 7:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing such a detailed answer with me. I must confess, the part about the matrix expression and the use of uint32_t is not very clear to me. If I may ask, how exactly do they work?

Comment: @D.Sanz `uint32_t` is just a [standard typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) for an unsigned integer 32bits wide. I prefer to be explicit, so it's obvious what type I work with no matter what platform I compile the code on.

Comment: @D.Sanz Regarding matrix expressions: The way OpenCV is written, [arithmetic operations](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) on arrays return a "matrix expression" (a special type). Combining a number of those operations in a single c++ expression allows the compiler to generate optimized code.

Comment: @D.Sanz In that particular snippet of code, I take advantage of OpenCV providing operator overloads that perform per-element division, multiplication and bitwise AND. Furthermore I use the expression `(1 << i)` to generate the sequence `[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]` -- dividing by those values is equivalent to right shift by 0-7 positions. Then I write an expression as if it was for a single element: `((pixel / (1<<i)) & 1) * 255` and let OpenCV apply it to the whole matrix in the most effective way (probably using SIMD, maybe multithreading).

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cv::imread` reads the image as BGR matrix, but you index the matrix as if it was one-channeled.

Just change the reading line to `Mat m1 = imread("grayscalerose.jpg", 0);` and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

`Mat Out (In / (1<<i))`, the division of it will generate an integer value that equals to "round operation", let's say if Mat Out (6/5) will be 2. But, in bit-slicing, it uses floor operation instead of round. Thus, for Mat Out (6/5) it should be 1 instead of 2. For some cases, the result will be quite similar. But, in other cases, it can be really different, especially for bit-plane near to MSB (most significant bits). CMIIW.

Comment: Why does my comment only appear only a little in the beginning ?

Full comment :
@Dan Mašek :  but, Mat Out (In / (1<<i)), the division of it will generate an integer value that equals to "round operation", let's say if Mat Out (6/5) will be 2. But, in bit-slicing, it uses floor operation instead of round. Thus, for Mat Out (6/5) it should be 1 instead of 2. For same case, he result will be quite similar. But, in other cases, it can be really different, especially for bit-plane near to MSB (most significant bits). CMIIW.